# Change session variables with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

Okey so I can't quite see how to do this but this is what I am trying to do. I need to update a SESSION that is used on multiply places on the website. I do this with ajax but when I change the SESSION it remains the same in the website as before the ajax call. here is an example:

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<script>
function sessionUpdate()
{ 
//Do a get ajax call that send the 2 parameters to updateSession.php
}
</script>

<?php
$_SESSION['foo'] = "foo"; 
$_SESSION['bar'] = "bar"; 

echo"<div>";
echo"<p  onclick="sessionUpdate()>Update Session</p>";

echo"{$_SESSION['foo']} {$_SESSION['bar']}";
echo"</div>";
?>
```

updateSession.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = "new foo"; 
$_SESSION['bar'] = "new bar";
?>
```

Now, the sessions are used al over the site so I can't just replace the information from the ajax call in the example div with a innerHTML=data.responseText; at just that place. Anyway when I do this teh echo of the foo and bar sessions don't change, are they just static variables that can't be changed without a page reload or what is the problem?

Comment: In your index.php, there are lines: `$_SESSION['foo'] = "foo"; 
$_SESSION['bar'] = "bar"; `. Do you have them in your real code? Are they executed always?

Comment: Yes, whan i first start index.php they are set to specific values, and as the used makes options on teh site those sessions will need to change as they contain information about the navigation.

Comment: How do you know that session is not changed? Also: `Now, the sessions are used al over the site so I can't just replace the information from the ajax call in the example div with a innerHTML=data.responseText; at just that place.` - that sounds like complete nonsense. Not clear what do you mean here.

Comment: Well since I echo the session and the echo has not changed after the ajax call I can tell it's the same, or well the session is actually changed but not regocnised on the site, becouse if i echo the sessions in teh updateSession.php file i get the new result. And what I ment about that was if I just wanted the text to change from the echo I could just replace it with a new echo from the file the ajax calls.

Comment: **Well since I echo the session** `and the echo has not changed after the ajax call I can tell it's the same` - as I understand, you mean echo in `index.php`, right?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you open `index.php` and example div contains default values of session variables ('foo bar' in your example). After you click Update Session, doing `innerHTML=data.responseText` you can see updated session values ('new foo new bar' according to example). But after you reload index.php - it shows 'foo bar' again. According to your code, you do not check if you should set default session variables. Try to replace in your index.php

```
<?php
$_SESSION['foo'] = "foo"; 
$_SESSION['bar'] = "bar"; 

echo"<div>";
```

With

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['foo']))
   $_SESSION['foo'] = "foo"; 
if(!isset($_SESSION['bar']))
   $_SESSION['bar'] = "bar"; 

echo"<div>";
```

Updated code will check if session variable is set (user open index.php at the first time). Once it is not set - default values will be assigned, but once that is done, it will not override any future changes (so, after ajax call foo and bar variables will be set and your code will not rewrite its values)

Comment: No, I am sorry if i am beeing unclear here. This si not the problem, the problem is that the session is used in multiple places on index.php and I can't do a innerHTML=data.responseText to update the value since it's used all over. my question is if there is some way for the session to update all over the page after changeing it with ajax.

Comment: @user1593846 Now I'm confused completely. What stops you from doing innerHTML = data.responseText? Are you saying that you have few places where session is echoed and you need to update all those places? Try to rephrase your question. Maybe with some examples like: I press that button, session is updated and I need to see...

Comment: Exactly what you said there, I need to update all the places the session occurs in.

Comment: Ok. Than, if you want to do something like that, you need simply wrap all echoed session variable in some span, for instance, with specific class (not ID - it must be unique). And than select them with [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName). It will return array which you will be able to update in a loop. Please note that this function is not cross browser (will not work in IE7 and, I think, 8)

Comment: okey, i thought about that becouse then i can just innerHTML the class but the problem is that I got the session as a variable on a onclick function, can  I really have a span inside?, looking like this  Onclick="thefunction(<span class="theSession">echo"'{$_SESSION['foo']'}, '{$_SESSION['bar']'}";</span>)"

Comment: You do not need it there. When on click happens, you already have that span on your page. So you need to find all those spans an replace their innerHTML. like `function thefunction(session1, session2)  { var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("theSession");
    for(var i =0; i< divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].innerHTML = session1 + " " session2;
    }  }`

Comment: But I must have a span around the session in the onclick. otherwise they wont change

Comment: Why they should not change? Why do you need it in onclick function? You should ALREADY have those spans on your page when onclick happens.  and with innerHTML you will simply change content of those spans.

Comment: well it's hard to explain but this is a slimed down version of what I am need to do http://pastebin.com/DM8tfDM5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21830/discussion-between-fangel-and-user1593846)